# Airflow, enable dag on creation

Tags: python, airflow

When I create a DAG with air flow in python I can pass some parameters.

```
SETTINGS = {
    'owner': 'hello',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
 }
dag = DAG(dag_id,
              schedule_interval='@daily',
              catchup=False,
              default_args=SETTINGS)
```

Yet when I do so, I still have to go on the interface and to enable the DAG with a click. I would like to know if there is a settings to pass to do it directly on creation. I think it has something to do with "pause" but can't find the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Change `dags_are_paused_at_creation` in `airflow.cfg` to `False`. The default value is `True`, so your dags are paused at creation.

```
[core]
dags_are_paused_at_creation = False
```

Set the following environment variable.

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION=False
```

If you want to limit this setting for a single DAG you can set `is_paused_upon_creation` DAG parameter to `True`.

Example:

```
DAG(dag_id='my-dag', is_paused_upon_creation=True)
```

Comment: Can I set it in the python script ? I don't have access to astromer configuration and stuff.

Comment: Yes you can, Example: `DAG(dag_id='my-dag', is_paused_upon_creation=True)`

Comment: Can I add it in my SETTINGS dict I did in my example.

Comment: No, your SETTINGS dict is for default_args for a task. This is a DAG level property. So you need something like `dag = DAG(dag_id, schedule_interval='@daily', catchup=False, default_args=SETTINGS, is_paused_upon_creation=True)`

Comment: Were you able to achieve using this feature , I am using 1.10.3 . Got an error as `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_paused_upon_creation'`

Answer (score 2):

There is a parameter for a DAG: `is_paused_upon_creation`. I haven't tried to use it, but you can find some information in the source code: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py